# How to get new hash value of URL without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I setup this script to capture clicks to  elements and grab the location.hash value:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    filenamehash=location.hash;
    console.log(filename);
    console.log(filenamehash);
});
```

The problem is, the value of the hash doesn't seem to change until after the function completes. So if I click a new hash value in my page, the above script doesn't catch it. If I click it a second time, it does.

Do I need a delay of some kind? Or perhaps "on click finish" event (if there is such a thing?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just listen for the hash change instead

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    console.log( window.location.hash );
});
```

or if the hash is the anchors href, just get that

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var filenamehash = $(this).attr('href');

    console.log(filenamehash);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was not aware of the "hashchange" event!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent default at the same time? I tried e.preventDefault(); but my page is still jumping to the anchors (I want to control the jumping myself via Javascript).